# Adding variable data to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jwplayer

I have the following Javascript for playing music files as playlist using jwplayer

```
function playAllAudio() {
var audioDiv = "<div id='audioplayer'></div>";
    //Get ids from selected files
var sData = $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();

$.post("mediaStream.do", {OID : sData},function(data) {     
    jwplayer('audioplayer').setup({
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '470',
        'height': '24',
        //'playlist': [{file:'mp3:audio/audioMotion'},{file:'mp3:audio/audioTangled'},{file:'mp3:audio/audioSunHands'}],
         'playlist': data,
        'provider': 'rtmp',
        'streamer': 'rtmp://XXXXXXX.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st',
        'modes': [
            {type: 'flash', src: 'https://YYYYYYYYY.cloudfront.net/player.swf'}
        ]
    });

});
}
```

with data being created dynamically as a JSON string, where the values are song filenames formatted for jwplayer

```
var data = "[{file:'mp3:audio/audioMotion'},{file:'mp3:audio/audioTangled'}]";
```

How ever, when i use the variable the 'data', the jwplayer does not work. How do i make it work with data passed from server to the javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data being created dynamically is a [JSON](http://json.org/) string, but the jwplayer's `playlist` config should be an array, you must cover the string to an array first:

```
var data = "[{file:'mp3:audio/audioMotion'},{file:'mp3:audio/audioTangled'}]";
data = JSON.parse(data); // with out IE8-
```

but `JSON` is not support in IE8-, you can use Douglas Crockford's [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to fixed it.

Comment: Excellent answer! I am using Douglas Crockdford's json2 and have solved the problem by doing JSON.parse(data) before adding to jwplayer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in just like you are doing so, as a response from the mediaStream.do call.

Are you sure the json is valid? Have you tried validating the response with http://jsonlint.com/?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll keep in mind the http://jsonlint.com/ site before posting any related questions the next time.